# How can I implement this view in Android

Tags: android, view

First i apologize for the question as i don't know how else to phrase it.

I saw this in an app called ['Flags of the World'](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funanduseful.flagsoftheworld.admob&hl=en) 
The same effect is available in android 2.3 and 4.1.2 devices.

[image: Screen Shot of the View]

I tried using ViewFlipper with simple slide animation but it only shows the leaving image and the incoming image. I would like to know if this is a widget or any suggestions on how i can implement this. (three images visible with the shrinking effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of time is passed since you asked this question, but... better late than never!
There's a custom view called [CoverFlow](https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/) that seems to do exactly what you asked.